# React-Native path rendering slowdown using requestAnimationFrame with polyline

Tags: android, react-native

I'm implementing a cardiac monitor like the blue line in [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=svbbw6Fq9oA) video. I'm using a Polyline and *requestAnimationFrame*. Starting with a Polyline of length 0, every frame adds another point to the Polyline in state and triggers a re-render. The animation starts off snappy and smooth but it gets slower and slower as the length of the Polyline increases.

I've tried throttling the framerate and I've replaced the waveform computation with something extremely simple and it still gets slower. I'm not sure, but I think this is because its re-rendering the entire Polyline every time - as the Polyline gets bigger, the renders take longer. I am running this component on an Android Nexus tablet.

```
componentDidMount() {    
    this.fps = 30;
    this.then = Date.now();
    this.interval = 1000 / this.fps;
    this._frameId = requestAnimationFrame(() => {
        this.renderFrame();
    });
}

renderFrame() {
    const stepsize = 5;
    x = this.x + stepsize;
    this.arrIndex += stepsize;
    y = this._waveform(this.arrIndex);

    if (x < this.state.dimensions.width) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
        var newPoint = x + "," + y + " "
        this.path += newPoint
        this.setState({path:this.path});
    } else {
        this.x = 0;
        this.y = 50;
        this.path = ""
    }
    this._frameId = requestAnimationFrame(this.renderFrame);
}

render() {
    return (
        <View style={{ flex: 1, alignSelf: 'stretch' }} onLayout={this.onLayout} >
        <Svg height={this.state.dimensions.height} width={this.state.dimensions.width}>
        <Polyline points={this.state.path}
            fill="none"
            stroke="green"
            strokeWidth="1"/>
        <Rect x={this.x -5} width="10" height={this.state.dimensions.height} fill="#1c2321"/>
        </Svg>
        </View>);
}
```

The monitor should smoothly render at the same rate for each pass, but its much faster at the beginning and gets progressively slower as it carries on.